# Basic Arithmetic with passed URL variables via PHP?

Tags: php, url, variables

I'm trying to do some very basic arithmetic and am getting hung up.  I'm pulling variables from a URL like this:

http://mysite.com/page.php?var1=100&var=5

This is the basic /page.php code I'm using:

```
<?php
$var1 = "var1";
$var2 = "var2";
$divided_amount = $var1/$var1;
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Derp</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">

        <div style="text-align: center; width: 1000px; background-color: #fff; margin: auto;">

<p>This should be the divided amount: <?php echo $divided_amount ?> </p>


</body>
</html>
```

However, I end up getting this error message:

```
Warning: Division by zero in /derp.php on line 4
```

Is this even possible to do with passed variables?  If so, where am I going wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing a string by another string. Try replacing your PHP code with this:

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET["var1"];
$var2 = $_GET["var2"];
if(is_numeric($var1) && is_numeric($var2) && $var2 != 0)
{
    // Perform division only if the variables are numeric and $var2 is not 0
    $divided_amount = $var1/$var2;
}
else
{
    // Value to be displayed if division is not possible.
    $divided_amount = 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: is this (PHP arithmetic) even possible to do with passed variables?

A: Sure.

> Q: Where am I going wrong?

A: You're assigning strings ("var1") to your variables, then trying to do arithmetic with them.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$var1 = 4;
$var2 = 2;
$divided_amount = $var1/$var1;
?>
```

At a minimum, you might want to test with is_numeric() before performing arithmetic:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your variables via `$_GET`
eg:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
if (isset($_GET['var1']) && isset($_GET['var'])) {
    $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
    $var = $_GET['var'];
    $sum = $var1 / $var;
}
?>
```